# Custom Module Add Customers Automatically in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have a custom module where i have inherited res.partner.I have a field "doctor"(which is many2one field).When i create a customer i can select a doctor.In img 1 Willam is the customer and he has selected Nitesh as the doctor.I have created doctor_view.xml which will show all the details of the Doctor.Now in img 2 , as we have selected "Nitesh" as 'Doctor' for 'Customer Willam',i should display "Willam" under "Client" in img2. Can anyone help me in this?Thanks in advance
[image: Img1]
[image: Img2]

My code

Customer.py

```
from qrcode import *
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class res_partner(osv.osv):
 _inherit = "res.partner"
 _description = "adding fields to res.partner"
 _columns = { 

    'doctor': fields.many2one('crm.lead.doctor','Doctor'),
 }
 class crm_lead_doctor(osv.osv):
    _name = "crm.lead.doctor"
    _order = "name"
    _columns ={
        'name':fields.char('Doctor Name',required=True,size=64,translate=True),
        'doctor_id':fields.char('Doctor Id',size=64,readonly=True),
        'doctor_mobile': fields.char('Mobile',required=True,size=64),
        'doctor_email': fields.char('Email',size=64),
        'doctor_hospital': fields.many2one('crm.lead.hospital','Hospital'),
        'doctor_street': fields.char('Street', size=128),
        'doctor_street2': fields.char('Street2', size=128),
        'doctor_zip': fields.char('Zip', change_default=True, size=24),
        'doctor_city': fields.char('City', size=128),
        'doctor_state_id': fields.many2one("res.country.state", 'State'),
        'doctor_country_id': fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country'),
        'doctor_brochure': fields.char('Brochuer',size=64),
        'doctor_flyer': fields.char('Flyer',size=64),
        'doctor_training': fields.char('Training',size=64),
        'doctor_starterpacksent': fields.char('Strater pack sent',size=64),
        'doctor_no_of_deliveries': fields.char('No of Deliveries/year',size=64),
        'doctor_fee': fields.char('Fee',size=64),
        'doctor_registration': fields.char('Registration No',size=64),
        'doctor_pancard': fields.char('Pan Card No',size=64),
        'doctor_fiscalcode': fields.char('Fiscal Code',size=64),
        'doctor_iban': fields.char('IBAN',size=64),
        'doctor_contractset': fields.char('Contract Set',size=64),
        'doctor_contractrecieved': fields.char('Contract Recieved',size=64),
        'doctor_clients':fields.many2many('res.partner')
    }
    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context={}):
        doc_seq = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'master.doctor')
        vals['doctor_id'] = doc_seq
        res = super(res_partner.crm_lead_doctor, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
        return res
```

Doctor_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="view_doctor_form_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.doctor.form</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead.doctor</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Doctor Details" version="7.0">
            <group>
                <field name="name"/>
<!--                 <field name="doctor_id"/> -->
                <field name="doctor_mobile"/>
                <field name="doctor_email"/>
                <field name="doctor_hospital"/>
                <label for="street" string="Doctor Address"/>
                <div>
                    <field name="doctor_street" placeholder="Street..."/>
                    <field name="doctor_street2"/>
                    <div class="address_format">
                        <field name="doctor_city" placeholder="City" style="width: 40%%"/>
                        <field name="doctor_state_id" on_change="onchange_state(state_id)" options='{"no_open": True}' placeholder="State" style="width: 24%%"/>
                        <field name="doctor_zip" placeholder="ZIP" style="width: 34%%"/>
                    </div>
                    <field name="doctor_country_id" placeholder="Country" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
                </div>
            </group>
            <notebook>
                <page string="Sales">
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="doctor_brochure"/>
                            <field name="doctor_flyer"/>
                            <field name="doctor_training"/>
                            <field name="doctor_starterpacksent"/>
                            <field name="doctor_no_of_deliveries"/>
                            <field name="doctor_fee"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="doctor_registration"/>
                            <field name="doctor_pancard"/>
                            <field name="doctor_fiscalcode"/>
                            <field name="doctor_iban"/>
                            <field name="doctor_contractset"/>
                            <field name="doctor_contractrecieved"/> 
                        </group> 
                    </group>
                </page>
                <page string="Clients">
                   <field name="doctor_clients"/>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </form>
    </field>
    </record>
<record id="view_doctor_tree_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.doctor.tree</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead.doctor</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Doctor Details" version="7.0">
                <field name="doctor_id"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="doctor_mobile"/>
                <field name="doctor_email"/>
                <field name="doctor_hospital"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    </record>

    <record id="new_doctor" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Doctors</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">crm.lead.doctor</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_doctor_tree_extended"/>
    </record>

<!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
<menuitem name ="Doctors - Hospitals" id = "menu_lead" />
  <menuitem name="Doctors" id="sub_menu_lead" parent="menu_lead" />
    <menuitem name="Doctors" id="create_lead" parent="sub_menu_lead" action="new_doctor"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1):

that's a perfect example for a one2many relationship between doctor-client. if you would realise it that way in openerp, you will have the clients shown in your doctor-view.

many2many would make sense, if your client has more than one doctor.

little hint: `'doctor_clients':fields.one2many('res.partner','doctor')`

```
from qrcode import *
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class res_partner(osv.osv):
 _inherit = "res.partner"
 _description = "adding fields to res.partner"
 _columns = { 

    'doctor': fields.many2one('crm.lead.doctor','Doctor'), #the so called relation_field for the one2many relation to crm.lead.doctor
 }
 class crm_lead_doctor(osv.osv):
    _name = "crm.lead.doctor"
    _order = "name"
    _columns ={
        'name':fields.char('Doctor Name',required=True,size=64,translate=True),
        'doctor_id':fields.char('Doctor Id',size=64,readonly=True),
        'doctor_mobile': fields.char('Mobile',required=True,size=64),
        'doctor_email': fields.char('Email',size=64),
        'doctor_hospital': fields.many2one('crm.lead.hospital','Hospital'),
        'doctor_street': fields.char('Street', size=128),
        'doctor_street2': fields.char('Street2', size=128),
        'doctor_zip': fields.char('Zip', change_default=True, size=24),
        'doctor_city': fields.char('City', size=128),
        'doctor_state_id': fields.many2one("res.country.state", 'State'),
        'doctor_country_id': fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country'),
        'doctor_brochure': fields.char('Brochuer',size=64),
        'doctor_flyer': fields.char('Flyer',size=64),
        'doctor_training': fields.char('Training',size=64),
        'doctor_starterpacksent': fields.char('Strater pack sent',size=64),
        'doctor_no_of_deliveries': fields.char('No of Deliveries/year',size=64),
        'doctor_fee': fields.char('Fee',size=64),
        'doctor_registration': fields.char('Registration No',size=64),
        'doctor_pancard': fields.char('Pan Card No',size=64),
        'doctor_fiscalcode': fields.char('Fiscal Code',size=64),
        'doctor_iban': fields.char('IBAN',size=64),
        'doctor_contractset': fields.char('Contract Set',size=64),
        'doctor_contractrecieved': fields.char('Contract Recieved',size=64),
        'doctor_clients':fields.one2many('res.partner','doctor','Clients') #here we use 'doctor' the new field of res.partner as relation_field to bind the relation
    }
    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context={}):
        doc_seq = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'master.doctor')
        vals['doctor_id'] = doc_seq
        res = super(res_partner.crm_lead_doctor, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
```

the views are just fine
            return res

Comment: :Thank's for the answer.It wasn't helpful for me.         My problem is, how can i add customer to Doctor automatically after i create a customer

Comment: if you have a one2many relationship between doctor-client and you allready have created some doctors, you could create clients and choose a doctor on them and they will automatically be seen in the doctors clients field.

Comment: It is not happening. 'doctor_clients':fields.one2many('res.partner','doctor') is doctor client field and 'doctor': fields.many2one('crm.lead.doctor','Doctor'), is the doctor field. Can you please say me where did i go wrong

Comment: i don't see any problems with your code. i tried a fast test with simply extending res.partner with many2one and creating a new model doctor.doctor (views, one2many field, ...). i create a new doctor and after that i set him up in some res.partner. loading the doctor (form) is showing me all the res.partner i've added the doctor in.

Comment: cause you're using a many2many field in your screenshots. but you have to use one2many, then there won't be an add button, instead something like "add new item", which you won't need, cause by setting the doctor in the client (res.partner), the clients will show on the doctors automatically.

Comment: sorry i never coded anything, i justed tested in openerp (you can create models and views there too), cause i had no time for more than that. but i edited my answer with the code you should use :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to see the customer under the doctor's clients?

The customer will show under the doctor's clients only once you save the customer. Before you save, the link is not created so it wont show in the doctor's form view.

If you save the customer, and then open the doctor it should show as a client.